# sintaxe criteria usando yii framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Estou com dificuldades para realizar um `where` usando criteria, estou postando o codigo que estou fazendo e abaixo a o erro..

Codigo Criteria

```
$criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('data_hora',$this->data_hora,true);
        $criteria->compare('arquivo',$this->arquivo,true);
        $criteria->compare('caminho',$this->caminho,true);
        $criteria->condition="caminho=".$_POST['busca'];
```

Erro Gerado

> CDbCommand falhou ao executar o comando SQL: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
>   error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near
>   '/home/samba/Administracao/scordon/cdgrd/cdgrd.scp' at line 1. The SQL
>   statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `path` `t` WHERE
>   caminho=/home/samba/Administracao/scordon/cdgrd/cdgrd.scp
>   (/opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/framework/db/CDbCommand.php:543)

Comment: Pode postar a sql gerada por esse código?

Comment: não consigo pegar a sql, as funções do sql são gerados por codigos do yii framework

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$criteria->compare('caminho', $_POST['busca']);
```

Desta forma o Yii ja filtra contra [SQL Injection](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL). Da forma abaixo - conforme a resposta do milz - o sistema fica vulnerável a [SQL Injection](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL).

```
$criteria->condition="caminho='".$_POST['busca']."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro aparenta ser um problema no WHERE, sendo que a query que está a ser executada é:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM path t WHERE caminho=/home/samba/Administracao/scordon/cdgrd/cdgrd.scp
```

e deverá ser

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM path t WHERE caminho='/home/samba/Administracao/scordon/cdgrd/cdgrd.scp'
```

Altere a linha do condition para:

```
$criteria->condition="caminho='".$_POST['busca']."'";
```

Desta forma a query já não deverá produzir nenhum erro.